# Are immutable julia structs ever safe to mutate and under what conditions can it be done in safe way?

Tags: c, julia

Inspired by the post [at Julia discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/are-immutable-struct-really-immutable/26138) I would like to ask the same question but with a catch.

Consider:

```
struct HappyImmutable
  a::Int
end
```

I cannot change the field a. it is of course immutable:

```
julia> struct HappyImmutable
   a::Int
   end

julia> b = HappyImmutable(1)
julia> b.a
1

julia> b.a = 2
ERROR: setfield! immutable struct of type HappyImmutable cannot be changed
Stacktrace:
 [1] setproperty!(::HappyImmutable, ::Symbol, ::Int64) at ./sysimg.jl:19
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

This makes perfect sense to me. However, reading through the Julia sources I see that there is one ifstatement preventing me from mutating the struct.

```
 JL_CALLABLE(jl_f_setfield)
    {
        JL_NARGS(setfield!, 3, 3);
        jl_value_t *v = args[0];
        jl_value_t *vt = (jl_value_t*)jl_typeof(v);
        if (vt == (jl_value_t*)jl_module_type)
            jl_error("cannot assign variables in other modules");
        if (!jl_is_datatype(vt))
            jl_type_error("setfield!", (jl_value_t*)jl_datatype_type, v);
        jl_datatype_t *st = (jl_datatype_t*)vt;
        if (!st->mutabl)
            jl_errorf("setfield! immutable struct of type %s cannot be changed", jl_symbol_name(st->name->name));
        size_t idx;
        if (jl_is_long(args[1])) {
            idx = jl_unbox_long(args[1]) - 1;
            if (idx >= jl_datatype_nfields(st))
                jl_bounds_error(args[0], args[1]);
        }
        else {
            JL_TYPECHK(setfield!, symbol, args[1]);
            idx = jl_field_index(st, (jl_sym_t*)args[1], 1);
        }
        jl_value_t *ft = jl_field_type(st,idx);
        if (!jl_isa(args[2], ft)) {
            jl_type_error("setfield!", ft, args[2]);
        }
        jl_set_nth_field(v, idx, args[2]);
        return args[2];
    }
```

By removing that if-statement and implementing my own setfield! I guess I can indeed mutate the struct. The question is, what consequences and can of worms will I open by doing this? Is it ever safe to do?

**Edit** 
It seems that some misunderstood me I do not indent to modify the language itself, rather declaring an external C function that does the same thing as the runtime defined function.

Comment: given the types of things declaring a struct immutable lets a compiler do, this would almost certainly be a very bad idea

Comment: Of course, I am aware that this is not a good idea. I have some experience with compiler runtimes albeit limited and for performance reasons, it might under certain circumstances be worth it to circumvent immutability. Still that requires knowledge on how the runtime and garbage collector et. cetera operates, knowledge that I lack : )

Comment: *"Is it ever safe to do?"* Nope, mutable vs. immutable is a fundamental design choice. You can't just go and arbitrarily change it in one place. You'd have to redesign the language from scratch.

Comment: @user3386109 I have clarified in my post that I do not indent to modify the source language

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're proposing to pass the `st` pointer to a C function, and allow that function to modify the object that `st` points to. If the Julia language specification doesn't specifically prohibit C functions from modifying Julia objects, then the language specification sorely needs an update. The ability to call C functions is almost certainly intended to allow the use of existing libraries, e.g. math libraries with functions like `sin`, `cos`, and `pow`. And it's almost certainly **not** intended to allow C functions to muck around with the internals of Julia objects.

Comment: @user3386109 It is possible to do it yes. However, it is of course not recommended to do so, which I understand fully (And also stated in my question).

Comment: So then what is your question? To quote your comments: *"Of course, I am aware that this is not a good idea."* and *"it is of course not recommended to do so"*. What more are you looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198203/discussion-between-jkrt-and-user3386109).

Comment: Well, the question formulated as "if I do this, what kinds of bad things would actually happen and why?" isn't a bad one.

Comment: @phg Feel free to edit my post, to clarify it further it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you modify the language implementation in way to allow breaking the rules of the language as specified, you can do whatever you want. However:

1. The language you're working with is no longer Julia, and
2. Whatever changes you make may introduce bugs. If you add backdoors to allow violation of constraints of the original language, you may very well find that other parts of the language implementation that you haven't yet examined are making use of invariants depending on those language constraints, and that, without making significant changes elsewhere, your changes end up being bugs.

What you're trying to do sounds highly inadvisible.

Comment: To clarify the Julia language does allow calling user-defined C-sources through it's FFI and the assignment syntax above is syntactic sugar for setfield! So by implementing my own setfield! outside of the compiler, I would not change the language, since I can do what I described above without changing the language implementation.

Comment: Surely either the language is underspecified or doing that is explicitly undefined behavior.